# Using an array, how do I store and display the unique numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, unique

Hello again Stack Overflow, I'm now just learning about arrays in my programming class and its now becoming very confusing for me and I can't seem to write the correct code for it. I've managed to get most of it done and I cant seem to get the correct code for my if statement on line 25 and I'm also getting a cannot find symbol on line 12. The output for the program should display the number after the user inputs it and continue a small list and let the user know if they already entered the same number. The output will look similar to this:

```
Enter number: 11
11
Enter number: 85
11 85
Enter number: 26
11 85 26
Enter number: 11
11 has already been entered
11 85 26
```

Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Unique
{
public void getNumbers()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numbers = new int [5];
    int count = 0; // unique numbers read
    int entered = 0; // entered numbers

    while( entered < numbers.length)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        if (number >= 10 && number <= 100)
        {
            boolean containsNumber = false;
            entered++;

            for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
            numbers[a]=number;                  

            if (!containsNumber)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
                System.out.printf("%d has already been entered\n", number);
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("number must be between 10 and 100");
            System.out.printf("%d\n",number);
            for(int value:numbers)
            System.out.printf("   %d\n", value);
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone show me exactly what I'm doing wrong because I feel like my for statement is wrong as well.

Comment: What is the output you get? You should add that to your question so we can compare expected vs actual output.

Comment: First thing I see is that `containsNumber` will always be false because no where in your code do you change it. Second thing is that when a user enters a number you set every position in the array to that number. Last thing I see is that you have `entered < numbers.length` but I never see you make the variable `numbers`. I think you meant `array.length`.

Comment: First thing I see is your for loop makes every number in the array the same

Comment: Unfortunately, my code does not compile as it appears because I'm stuck on my inner for and if statements. I can also tell none of you read what I stated in the beginning. I'm new to java. I know my code is not finished and will NOT give me the output I want. I'm simply asking for help, not to be criticized for the mistakes I already know about.

Comment: `numbers.length` Where is `numbers` from?

Comment: Have you learnt about functions yet?

Comment: To help you I **MUST** point out mistakes. I'm honestly not trying to criticize you. If you know what is wrong you can then try to work on those things.

Comment: @user3189142 I have not learned about functions yet. Since your asking I'm going to assume it would be easier but I want to get my expected output with the code I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
numbers[a]=number;
```

Assuming from the code around this `for`, perhaps you want to check whether `number` is already entered or not. Then, it must be

```
for (int a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++)
{
    if (numbers[a] == number)
    {
        containsNumber = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And you should append user's input if it's not already entered. then, you should do it.

```
if (!containsNumber)
{
    numbers[count] = number;
    count++;
}
```

Also, `entered` variable is not needed - the size of `numbers` is `count`, isn't it?

```
while (count < numbers.length)
{
    ...
```

Last, this code is wrong.

```
System.out.printf("%d\n",number);
for(int value:numbers)
System.out.printf("   %d\n", value);
```

Although `numbers.length` is *always* 5, the size of *real* contents of numbers is `count`. So, we should do

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    System.out.printf("   %d\n", numbers[i]);
}
```

And the print code `System.out.printf("%d\n",number);` should not be executed when the number is already entered, because `System.out.printf("%d has already been entered\n", number);` already print message. So, it should be moved to

```
if (!containsNumber)
{
    numbers[count] = number;
    count++;
    // here
    System.out.printf("%d\n",number);
}
```

Therefore, the code should be

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Unique
{
    public void getNumbers()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbers = new int [5];
        int count = 0; // unique numbers read

        while (count < numbers.length)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if (number >= 10 && number <= 100)
            {
                boolean containsNumber = false;

                for (int a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++)
                {
                    if (numbers[a] == number)
                    {
                        containsNumber = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }                 

                if (!containsNumber)
                {
                    numbers[count] = number;
                    count++;

                    System.out.printf("%d\n",number);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.printf("%d has already been entered\n", number);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("number must be between 10 and 100");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("   %d\n", numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/s6pmGC)

Notice that my code's format. Your original code is so hard to read >o<

Comment: I'm sorry if my code is messy which is why I'm in the middle of learning java. Thank you so much for the help. When I tried to implement what user3189142 suggested I had trouble with the output and tried to fix it myself. Now I need to save this so I have something to fall back on if i make the same errors again.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, *very* close. Your for loop is almost complete, you just need to put an if inside it. From this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
    numbers[a]=number;
```

To something like this:

```
for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
{
    if (array[a] == number)
    {
        containsNumber = true;
        break; //This exits the for loop, so you don't continue unneedlessly
    }
}
```

Then, your if statement to increase count will work, and you just need to change that to add the number to the array

Comment: This was the kind of help I was looking for. I knew I was close I just was unsure of how to implement the code because I briefly learned about arrays last week. This is why I'm having a rough time with this.